# How do Tag Helpers differ from the Helper class?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

ASP.Net MVC 6 introduced Tag helpers feature.

Why should we use tag helpers over the Helper class provided by previous versions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Tag Helpers were introduced for several reasons.  [Scott Hanselman talks in length about them here.](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNET5VNextWorkInProgressExploringTagHelpers.aspx) However, the points for Tag Helpers include:

## Front-end developers do not need knowledge of C# to write them.

The following is really not very intuitive for a traditional front-end developer.

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title, new { @class = "control-label" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

However, it gets much more clear using tag helpers:

```
<label asp-for="Title" class="control-label" />
<input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />
```

*Note that this was in flux last I checked, including whether or not to use the `asp-` prefix.*

## It makes it easier to add other attributes, such as `class`, `placeholder`, or even other custom attributes.

I use angular.js with my projects; for this, the syntax becomes even more confusing:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title, new { @class = "form-control", ng_model = "ctrl.title" })
```

Now it's as simple as adding the attribute, like we'd expect:

```
<input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" ng-model="ctrl.title" />
```

## You can even write your own.

I'm not going to go in depth here, but you can create server-side expanding widgets that can even match your client-side frameworks for SEO purposes. There's a pretty decent [tutorial for making tag helpers](http://www.jeffreyfritz.com/2014/11/get-started-with-asp-net-mvc-taghelpers/).

Comment: Frontend developers can learn a little C# if they need to. No developer should ever be afraid to learn. You can write your own Razor syntax and add to your own attributes. I think the real reason is because it makes your markup looks like markup and not a hack.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the big reason is that it makes your markup cleaner; looking less like server-side code and more like HTML5.